# Element. remove does't work. (innerHTML work correct)

Tags: javascript, element

I want to validate my form. When field is empty, show warning alert.
and delete it after 3 sec. And here is problem. .remove doesent work. When i change it on .innerHTML="" it's work. But it's not delete this element.
Thanks for all com!

here is code:

```
if(intMarks=="" || intImportance=="" || subject=="" || paragraph=="" ){
        body = document.getElementById("body")
        var warning = document.createElement("div");
        warning.classList.add("alert", "alert-danger");
        warning.setAttribute("role","alert");
        warning.innerText = "one of the fields is empty!";
        warning.setAttribute("id", "warning");
        body.appendChild(warning);
        //delete warning after 3 sec
        setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById("warning").remove;  console.log("delete") }, 3000);
```

Comment: IIRC you remove an element *from its parent*. You're also not calling `remove`. And the method you're after is [`removeChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild)

Comment: Try document.getElementById("warning").remove();

Comment: Your timeout is 1sec not 3sec and you use `removeChild()` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have  to remove the element from its parent :

```
var elem = document.getElementById("warning");
elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
```

Comment: Oh God.. It's work! Thanks, for very fast answer! :)